# ESRI Web App - Publish publicly with login dialog

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-online

I have an ESRI web app hosted online I want to share outside my organization and the users on the other side don't have ESRI org handles. So I can't add them to a group and then grant them access.

I want to share this web page publicly, but to add security level of required user name and password via regular login dialog.

1. Is any other option within ESRI world before jumping into pure web development of implementing login dialog?
2. The plain vanilla way is to modify the generated JS code by adding login dialog. Eventually the app will be hosted online, but for the login part we need to set up local web server that will handle login requests, so we will have 2 servers accessed from single app. Is this something possible?

All in all seems like the thing I need is too popular use case.

Comment: Can you not add a login and password to the data on the server side?

Comment: @KeaganAllan Can you please explain, not sure I understood...

Comment: is the data hosted on ESRI or your own server? if your own server just password protect it via a group user and generate a generic user/pass to share with desired users.